# package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am having an issue with the above package in MVC 4. The validations don't fire even after pressing a button to post the data. The only ones that fire are the ones from the DataAnnotationsExtensions namespace which include the Required and Email attribute only after I try to submit the data.

Below, is the code I used for the LogOnModel, which worked fine under MVC 3:

```
public class LogOnModel 
    { 
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")] 
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinLength6")] 
        [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources))] 
        public string UserName { get; set; } 

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")] 
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] 
        [Email(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Email")] 
        public string Email { get; set; } 

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")] 
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinLength6")] 
        [DataType(DataType.Password)] 
        [Display(Name = "Password4", ResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources))] 
        public string Password { get; set; } 

        [Display(Name = "AcctRemember", ResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources))] 
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; } 
    }
```

This is the authors site: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx   and his reply to another person using them (dated 8/10/2012)  "I've tested that the current NuGet package will work fine in MVC4, using both .NET 4.0 and 4.5."

Below, is my setup for my scripts in my masterpage:

```
<head> 
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.blueopal.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.web.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/jquery.min.js")"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.all.min.js")"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () 
        { 
            $("#editor-field").css("border", "2px solid #f00"); 
            var strErrCode = '@TempData["ErrCode"]'; 
            switch (strErrCode) 
            { 
                case 'CustView': 
                    alert('@(Resources.CustViewErr)'); 
                    break; 
                case 'CustErr': 
                    alert('@(ViewBag.Error)'); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    { 
                        if (strErrCode != "") 
                            alert(strErrCode); 
                    } 
                    break; 
            } 
        }); 
    </script> 
    <script> 
        function error_handler(e) 
        { 
            if (e.errors) 
            { 
                var message = "Errors:\n"; 
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) 
                { 
                    if ('errors' in value) 
                    { 
                        $.each(value.errors, function () 
                        { 
                            message += this + "\n"; 
                        }); 
                    } 
                }); 
                alert(message); 
            } 
        } 
    </script> 
</head>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.... I'm dead in the water here with no other place to turn....

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is that all the following work with the DataAnnotationExtensions & ExtensionsDataAnnotations.ClientValidation dlls.

However, the Min & Maxlength Dataannotations no longer work in MVC4! It was driving me crazy!

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
         [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinMaxLength", MinimumLength = 6)]
         //[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 2)]
         //[Range(1, 100)]
         //[Min(3)]
         //[MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Name must be more than 5 characters")]
         //[MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Name must be more than 5 characters")]
         [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(YeagerTechResources.Resources))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions to validate integers,

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The number must be an integer")]
public int Number {get; set;}
```

I do think that this is the easiest way to solve the problem.